# OpenCV in C++: "Unknown Type Name"

Tags: c++, opencv, xcode6

I'm trying to follow along with the OpenCV tutorial, found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_features2d.html?highlight=surf). Part of the tutorial is to create a SURF feature detector.

Unlike the tutorial, my code is in a header file, like this:

```
class Img {
    Mat mat;
    int minHessian = 400;
    SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);

    public:
        ...
}
```

The error I'm getting occurs on the line

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);
```

and the error is:

```
Unknown type name 'minHessian'
```

When I do not put this in a separate class, the compiler does not complain. I have also checked and I have imported the required libraries.

Can anybody tell me what the error is, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the opencv tutorial code:

```
Mat img1 = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat img2 = imread(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
if(img1.empty() || img2.empty())
{
    printf("Can't read one of the images\n");
    return -1;
}

// detecting keypoints
SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
....
```

ans as I understand, in this code, the `SurfFeatureDetector detector(minHessian);` is not a signature of a function that you can write in your header file as you did; but it's actually calling the `SurfFeatureDetector` function in the code.
So, I think if you remove it from your header file code, and put it in your function(s), where you want call it, it may work.